# Unit test fails with org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedVerificationException

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, testng

I've created some tests in Mockito for verifying that other presenters call specific methods during a main presenter's initialization. The other presenters have been mocked.

The mocked presenters all implement the following interface:

```
public interface PresenterHasParent<V, P extends Presenter> extends Presenter<V> {

    public abstract void setParentPresenter(P presenter);
}
```

And the `Presenter` has the following setup:

```
public interface Presenter<V> {

    V getView();

    void initPresenter();
}
```

In my parent presenter class I have the following:

```
public class ParentPresenter() implements Presenter<ParentView>{
    private ParentView view;

    private ChildPresenterOne childPresenterOne;    
    private ChildPresenterTwo childPresenterTwo;    
    private ChildPresenterThree childPresenterThree;    
    private ChildPresenterFour childPresenterFour;

    @Inject
    public ParentPresenter(ParentView view, ChildPresenterOne childPresenterOne,
                                 ChildPresenterTwo childPresenterTwo,
                                 ChildPresenterThree childPresenterThree
                                 ChildPresenterFour childPresenterFour) {
        this.view = view;
        this.childPresenterOne= childPresenterOne;
        this.childPresenterTwo= childPresenterTwo;
        this.childPresenterThree= childPresenterThree;
        this.childPresenterFour= childPresenterFour;
    }

    //Other code

    @Override
    public void initPresenter() {
        view.setPresenter(this);

        childPresenterOne.initPresenter();
        childPresenterTwo.initPresenter();
        childPresenterThree.initPresenter();
        childPresenterFour.initPresenter();

        childPresenterOne.setParentPresenter(this);
        childPresenterTwo.setParentPresenter(this);
        childPresenterThree.setParentPresenter(this);
        childPresenterFour.setParentPresenter(this);

        registerHandlers();
    }
}
```

As you can see, we're using Injection to allow for easy unit test. I then create my mocked instances like so:

```
public class ParentPresenterTest {
    private List<PresenterHasParent> presenters;
    private ChildPresenterOne childPresenterOne;    
    private ChildPresenterTwo childPresenterTwo;    
    private ChildPresenterThree childPresenterThree;    
    private ChildPresenterFour childPresenterFour;
    private ParentPresenter parentPresenter;
    private View view;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() {
        presenters = new ArrayList<PresenterHasParent>();
        view = mock(View.class);        

        childPresenterOne= mock(ChildPresenterOne.class);
        presenters.add(childPresenterOne);

        childPresenterTwo= mock(ChildPresenterTwo.class);
        presenters.add(childPresenterTwo);

        childPresenterThree= mock(ChildPresenterThree.class);
        presenters.add(childPresenterThree);

        childPresenterFour= mock(ChildPresenterFour.class);
        presenters.add(childPresenterFour);

        parentPresenter = new ParentPresenter(view, childPresenterOne, childPresenterTwo, childPresenterThree, childPresenterFour);
    }

    @Test
    public void testInitPresenter() {
        parentPresenter.initPresenter();
        verify(view).setPresenter(parentPresenter);
        for(PresenterHasParent presenterToCheck : presenters) {

            Reporter.log("Testing the presenter " + presenterToCheck.getClass().getName(), true);

            verify(presenterToCheck).initPresenter();
            verify(presenterToCheck).setParentPresenter(parentPresenter);

            validateMockitoUsage();

            Reporter.log("Successfully tested the presenter " + presenterToCheck.getClass().getName(), true);
        }
    }
}
```

Upon running these tests, I get a failure on the 3rd or 4th presenter (Depending on what I do) which is:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedVerificationException: 
>   Missing method call for verify(mock) here:
>   -> at ParentPresenterTest.testInitPresenter(ParentPresenterTest.java:118)
>
> Example of correct verification:
>       verify(mock).doSomething()
>
> Also, this error might show up because you verify either of:
>   final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods. Those methods *cannot* be
>   stubbed/verified.
>
> at
>   ParentPresenterTest.testInitPresenter(ParentPresenterTest.java:119)

Now if it failed consistently, I could understand, but if I put breakpoints in and step over each method, it works fine. If I put no breakpoints in, it always fails and complains about the line (118) that reads on the 3rd presenter: `verify(presenterToCheck).setParentPresenter(presenter);`

I don't understand why it's failing, especially since it does work if I debug and step over the code. Can anyone shed any light on this perplexing issue?

**Edit**

So if I step over the 3rd presenter verify check and then run the code again, it will fail on the 4th one with the same issue. But if I step over the code for the 4th one as well, it works fine. Something very odd is happening here and since I can't debug to find the issue, it's making life quite difficult!

Comment: Is any threading involved in the code you're testing? as it sounds as a race condition, given that "sometimes it passes" when you add breakpoints.

Comment: @Augusto None, however I am aware that unit tests can be ran interleaved, but they should be referencing different objects. I've checked and made sure there are no other instances of the `ChildPresenter` objects, the only other one time one is called is when it is made into a concrete class and tests are ran on that. But putting breakpoints down shows that these are two different objects. So I'm quite confused by all of this

Comment: @Augusto I've done further checks and found that it only fails when I have no breakpoints and always on the 3rd child presenter. This is the one that is being made into a concrete class elsewhere. However, if I do breakpoints and step over each method, it works fine. How is my concrete version of a child presenter interfering with the test?

Comment: Could you try by replacing `@BeforeTest` by `@BeforeMethod`?

Comment: @JulienHerr Thanks for the advice, but I managed to find the issue. It was bad design implementation confusing Mockito. I've posted the fix below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of investigation, I found the issue. Due to the way I had created some super abstract classes (Before I had created the new interface), I was causing Mockito to get confused. It was a bit of bad design, but also Mockito behaving oddly.

The method that I was checking:

```
verify(presenterToCheck).setParentPresenter(parentPresenter);
```

Was an abstract method in the interface `PresenterHasParent`. However the objects that failed the test also implemented a `BaseEditPresenter`. This `BaseEditPresenter` didn't implement the interface `PresenterHasParent` but had their own version of the method `setParentPresenter()`. This was causing confusion with Mockito as it didn't know what method was truly called (Even though they did the same thing). It was strange though that it did work on step over, but never when the code was directly ran.

So to fix it, I had to clean up the design and make sure that the `BaseEditPresenter` had implemented the `PresenterHasParent` interface and not it's subclasses of `ChildPresenterThree` and `ChildPresenterFour`.

Comment: Not the truth. The root cause seems that the first invocation was not end compeletely, and then got the UnfinishedVerificationException when invoke again.